# Set Theme Not Working on Lower API Version

Tags: android, themes

I want to set up the whole application theme. And my code is working fine in ICe-Creme Sandwich and higher, but it is not working on lower versions, not it is giving any errors.

Here is my code :

I am setting the theme using the below code before calling setcontentView();

```
SharedPreferences pref=context.getSharedPreferences(HomeSAFEPref.HomeSAFEPref,0);
        int position= pref.getInt("BackgroundPosition", 0);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            context.setTheme(R.style.Background0);

            break;

        case 1:

            context.setTheme(R.style.Background1);

            break;

        case 2:

            context.setTheme(R.style.Background2);

            break;

        case 3:
            context.setTheme(R.style.Background3);
            break;

        case 4:
            context.setTheme(R.style.Background4);
            break;
        }
```

The above code is working fine with higher versions, but is not working with lower ones.

Here is the styles code :

```
<style name="Background0" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bigl_1</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Please suggest

Comment: same problem with me..Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your theme before you call super.onCreate() and setContentView(). If it still doesn't work, then it is probably a problem with the framework.

Refer [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3793).

Comment: But Siddharth,when i set theme before setContentView and afer super,This works fine for Samsung S3 and tab.But not working in below devices..Can u please tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: probably a bug fix that happened in 4.0+